# Вставка в БД Python

Tags: python, sql, база-данных, sqlite

Есть метод создания таблицы

```
def dbMaker():
    conn = sqlite3.connect(sqlite_file)
    conn.execute('''CREATE TABLE Goods
       (Gtin            INT     NOT NULL,
       Length           INT     NOT NULL,
       Width            INT     NOT NULL,
       Height           INT     NOT NULL,
       Weight           INT     NOT NULL,
       Data             Text    NOT NULL, 
       Multuplicator    INT,
       Gtin2            Text );''')
    print('Table were created')
```

Есть также метод для вставки

```
def insert(lineList):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(sqlite_file)
    c = conn.cursor()
    for item in lineList:
        c.execute('insert into Goods values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', item))
```

Подаю на вход list

```
ar=[1,2,3,4,5,'6',7,'8']
insert(ar)
```

Получаю ошибку `ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type`

В таблице и в list, типы совпадают же..

Comment: Может потому что ты вставляешь по одному `item` а не всю `lineList`. то есть `c.execute('insert into Goods values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', item) `выглядит вот так для первого в for `c.execute('insert into Goods values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', 1)`

Comment: Я не силен в python  но возможно нужно просто `c.execute('insert into Goods values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', lineList)`

Answer (score 1):

Вам не нужен цикл в функции `insert`.
Не плодите конекции, подключитесь один раз.
Вот исправленная функция:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(sqlite_file)
def insert(conn, lineList):
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('insert into Goods values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', lineList))
    conn.commit()
```